# How to properly interpolate between N-Dimensions in Simulink involving vector fields

Tags: matlab, vector, simulink

In MATLAB, I am trying to input a combination of currents (ex."5A, 5A, 5A, 5A") that range from -15A to 15A. The output should be a 3D vector field that shows the magnetic flux density, B, that is produced from this combination.

I have the pre-calculated vector fields from ANSYS maxwell that give the i, j, k vectors at each 3D coordinate. Therefore, the .txt file that is generated is:
x, y, z, <i, j, k>
...
for each combination of currents.

What I would like to do is interpolate a 10-dimensional grid that gives:
current_a, current_b, current_c, current_d, x,y,z, i, j, k
...
and have the final result be able to have the user input the desired combination of current, and visualize the interpolated vector field.

What I have already produced is the .txt/.csv file that contains:
current_a, current_b, current_c, current_d, x,y,z, i, j, k
by using the ANSYS API.

In Simulink, I have tinkered with the N-D pre-lookup table. However, I become stuck when it comes to configuring the settings and providing the inputs.

The Block Parameters of the N-D lookup table contains "Number of table dimensions" as 10, yet I am not sure how to classify the Breakpoint since we are working with vectors. The tutorials that I have seen primarily work with 1-D or 2-D lookup tables, so I have not been able to find that many resources that fit my need.

To clarify, the main piece of advice that I am looking for is how I should setup my Simulink model and block parameters with the given data, so that I may input very specific current inputs and visualize the instantaneous change in the vector field.